# Symfony submitting individual forms on page with multiple forms

Tags: forms, symfony, include, twig

My Symfony project consists of 3 bundles 2 of which provides forms.
I use twig in my view templates.

The first bundle has a view which includes the forms from the other 2 bundles.

My problem is when I attempt to submit either of the 2 included forms, the other form's required field is highlighted - which interferes with either of the forms submissions and data is not committed.

How I can have multiple forms on the same page which don't interfere with each others submission?

Comment: Do you have the forms in separate `<form>` tags?

Comment: @Maerlyn: your comment helped, thanks. The first twig template I included had no form_end at the end of the form. So, it seemed both forms became merged into one. If to provide an answer I'll mark it as correct. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not nesting the forms.

Something like this will be fine:

```
{{ form_start(myForm) }}
    {{ form_widget(myForm) }}
{{ form_end(myForm) }}

{{ form_start(anotherForm) }}
    {{ form_widget(anotherForm) }}
{{ form_end(anotherForm) }}
```

but something like this will not:

```
{{ form_start(myForm) }}
    {{ form_widget(myForm) }}

    {{ form_start(anotherForm) }}
        {{ form_widget(anotherForm) }}
    {{ form_end(anotherForm) }}
{{ form_end(myForm) }}
```